# IEnumerable<string> function c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, oop

i have faced this question in interview as below?

let us consider the string named

```
string gowtham="test1,test2,test3" ;
```

i need to **convert in to IEnumerable string function**

i need a output to be as

```
new[] {"test1", "test2","test3" }
```

what i did is i have created a string() function by spliting values by comma seperated as below

```
string[] mysamples= gowtham.Split(',');
```

i do not know how to proceed after

waiting for your responses?

Comment: I don't see the function you created. And I don't quite understand your problem.

Comment: You've converted a *string* to an *array of strings*. Those are data, not functions. And as a result, your `mysamples` object is of type `string[]`, which implements the desired interface `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: I don't think there's anything to add: arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so `mysamples` *is* already an `IEnumerable<string>`. Just wrap it up in a method with a return value of `IEnumerable<string>` and you're done.

Comment: @wRAR this is the function IEnumerable<string>

Comment: @LukeH sry i can not understand can u provide me some samples

Comment: @GowthamanSS no, this is not a function.

Comment: @LukeH i am getting response as {test1,test2,test3} but i need it as {"test1","test2","test3"}

Comment: @GowthamanSS No, you don't.

Comment: Do you have a `using system.LINQ` at the top of your class file, to enable IntelliSense for the extension methods?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, you can use a method like this;

```
public static IEnumerable<string> YourMethod()
{
     string gowtham = "test1,test2,test3";
     string[] mysamples = gowtham.Split(',');
     List<string> senum = new List<string>();

     foreach ( string s in mysamples )
     {
         senum.Add(s);
     }

     return senum as IEnumerable<string>;
}
```

Since `string[]` implements [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface, it seems you just need to cast it as `IEnumerable<T>`

**EDIT**: Since *Magnus* and *LukeH* warned me, there is an easy way also what you want to do.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> YourMethod()
{
     string gowtham = "test1,test2,test3";
     return gowtham .Split(',');
}
```

Comment: That seems unnecessary as `"test1,test2,test3".Split(',').AsEnumerable()` would do.

Comment: @Magnus: You don't even need the `AsEnumerable` call: if the method is typed as `IEnumerable<string>` then simply `return "test1,test2,test3".Split(',');` will do the trick.

Comment: @Magnus You are totally right. I just wrote this because it seems to me more simple, readable and understandable..

Comment: @LukeH and Magnus. Updated guys! Thanks.

Comment: @LukeH Yes the extra `AsEnumerable()` (which only does casting) is unnecessary if used as a return statement in a method that returns `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

Every array is already a IEnumerable, in your case if you want to explicit cast to one IEnumerable of string you could use

```
IEnumerable<string> mysamplesEnumerable = mysamples as IEnumerable<string>
```

if you interviewer wanted a function that did this you could do

```
    IEnumerable<string> SplitEnumByComa(string input)
    {
          return input.Split(',');
    }
```

Comment: OP may be confused by the absence of IntelliSense, if the `using system.LINQ` is missing. I remember that confused me when I was first learning C#.